# My checkbox does not stay checked once clicked (styling checkbox with css)

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox

I am using React and pure CSS to create a checkbox list and style them.

Without styling my checkbox works perfectly, it stays checked and registers the right value.

**However**, when I add the styling, if I click on a checkbox, the "check" does not stay. Basically, if I hove ron the checkbox the "check" appears, but if I click it, the "check" does not persists.

**My checkbox component**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../mystyles/Dropdown.css'


function Jurisdictions(props) {
  const [selectedOpts, setSelectedOpts] = React.useState(new Set());

  function handleChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const checked = event.target.checked;

    if (checked) {
      selectedOpts.add(value);

    } else {
      selectedOpts.delete(value);
    }

    setSelectedOpts(new Set(selectedOpts));
    props.onChange && props.onChange(Array.from(selectedOpts.values()));
  }

  return (
    <div className="dropdown-jurisdictions">
      {props.options.map((opt) => (
        <label className="item-list" key={opt}>
          {opt}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="opts"
            value={opt}
            onChange={handleChange}
            className="my-checkbox"
          />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}


export default Jurisdictions;
```

**My CSS styling - Dropdown.css**

```
.dropdown-jurisdictions {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: none;
  height: 170px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #3D5A80;
}




.my-checkbox {
  display: none;
}


label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
label:before {
  line-height: 20px;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before,
label:hover:before {
  content: "\2713";
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem is in my CSS but I cannot see the reason.
Maybe because `label` is a not at the same level of my `checkbox`?

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox component should have a property `checked={this.props.checked}` or something along those lines to indicate that it is in the checked state.

Your `handleChange` function should invert the state of your `checked` variable in `state` or `props`.

Comment: It it not a React problem. My checkbox works fine, it is the CSS that it is not persistent when the checkbox is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly you don't have a property called `checked` on `input`. I think you will need to add that property first. Though I don't think this would still work because the styling you are doing is of `sibling` and not to parent.

You can see this for parent element selector: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It it not a React problem. My checkbox works fine, it is the CSS that it is not persistent when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: You are using `checked` in `css` and you are not passing that attribute in `react`. Also, check the second part I have added a note about styling.